# I need to get my old files off of this laptop hard drive, I was told to order a SATA adapter but it doesn’t fit?

Tags: hard-drive

I hired someone to help me with my old computer and they instead ripped the insides out and handed me a blank disk (claiming they had transferred my files).

I need to find out what kind of adapter to buy as the one I ordered doesn’t seem to fit (it was a USB 3.0 to SATA adaptor).

It has 22 pins and it from an old (13-ish years old) Dell laptop. The model number is: HTS548040M9AT00. Here is a picture of a similar drive from eBay.

[image: HTS548040M9AT00]

Comment: I'm curious as to why your USB to SATA adapter doesn't fit. 22 pins would be SATA power (15 pins) + SATA data (7 pins). Your adapter should work with that. Can you upload a photo of your adapter and the hard drive so we can see exactly what's going on?

Comment: 13 years old sound more like IDE and you can get a combination IDE / SATA carrier in most electronic stores.

Comment: @John agreed but you would expect IDE to be 40 pins. The number of pins suggests the hard drive is SATA. A photo would be useful to clarify.

Comment: Voting to close because without a picture or even a part number for the drive, pretty much anything could be the case.

Comment: Agreed but if the drive was SATA it should have fit and does not so there seems to be some confusion

Comment: I tried to add a picture and was not allowed because my account is new.

Comment: @JessE in that case the hard drive model number should be enough.

Comment: It is about 43 pins total, plus the 4 separate pins

Comment: HTS548040M9AT00

Comment: Different pin count. This makes sense now. You need an IDE to USB adapter, as John said.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, does it matter if a couple of the pins are slightly bent?

Comment: You can use fine needlepoint pliers to very carefully straighten them. If too far bent, damage could occur when connecting.

Comment: Its is a laptop hard drive, you need an IDE to usb adapter that supports the smaller IDE interface Like this one....https://www.amazon.com/Vantec-CB-ISATAU2-Supports-2-5-Inch-5-25-Inch/dp/B000J01I1G

Comment: This is a 2,5" IDE drive. The cheapest approach would be a 2,5" to 3,5" IDE adapter. Those will split your PINs(after fixed) into an IDE part and a 4-PIN POWER-part. But you'll need an old motherboard that still supports standard IDE ports to transfer the data. They're on eBay for 1$+shipping. Or ask a computer-savvy friend of yours to check his cellar. (I just checked the computer I wrote this on and it still has a 3,5" IDE port :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the posts (to which I and others contributed), you need an IDE or IDE / SATA combination carrier with USB connection to the computer and you need to ensure pins are fairly straight.